# Force retrofit to load new data

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit to get my json data in my recycleview. It used to work fine couple of weeks ago but I ran code now then It only loads data one time and then as many times as I make change any text or add new value in json data, It always load the same initial data on loading. I haven't used any cache property and strange thing is once it loads first time, then if i delete my json then still it loads the data instead of throwing exception and giving error of json not found.

What am I missing. I changed the version of retrofit but it dosesn't seem to work. Here is my code of Mainactivity is

```html
 GetDataService service = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetDataService.class);

        Call<List<RetroPhoto>> call = service.getAllPhotos();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<RetroPhoto>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<RetroPhoto>> call, Response<List<RetroPhoto>> response) {
                progressDoalog.dismiss();
                generateDataList(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<RetroPhoto>> call, Throwable t) {
                progressDoalog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(NewsActivity.this, "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    /*Method to generate List of data using RecyclerView with custom adapter*/
    private void generateDataList(List<RetroPhoto> photoList) {
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.customRecyclerView);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,photoList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(NewsActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

and code of GetDataService is

```html
public interface GetDataService {

    @GET("b.json")
    Call<List<RetroPhoto>> getAllPhotos();
}
```

and my gradle is

```html
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
```

Thanks in advance for any help. I am banging my heads on floor over 3 hours on figuring out what excatly gone through in couple of weeks where I even didn't touch the code.

Answer (score 0):

I realized problem was from server side as I was using ipage hosing, the i moved json to other hosing and immediately changes were shown in app on request but ipage didn't. So code is fine.